# jQuery Dialog: Draggable attribute not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a jQuery confirm dialog. Everything works great except when I set the draggable attribute to false, the dialog is still draggable on Chrome and Firefox. Below is the code:

```
function ActionClick(url){
        $("#ConfirmDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: "Yes",
                    click: function(){
                        location.href = url;
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: "No",
                    click: function(){
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        $("#ConfirmDialog").dialog("open");
    }
```

Would that be related to the old versions of jQuery and jQueryUI that I am using? I am using jQuery 1.5.1 and jQueryUI 1.8.11.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/yQrRx/) works with `jQuery 1.4.4` and `jQuery ui 1.8.7`.
So, nothing wrong with this code.

Probably you have a relevant code that you didn't post.

Comment: @rexcfnghk When it happens, usually appear again later. So, I suggest you to investigate why it has been solved magically.

Comment: You are right! The bug reappeared! I was able to reproduce the bug now: The dialog box is only draggable for the first time it was triggered. FYI, I had an HTML button to trigger the dialog box, when I cancel the dialog box and then trigger it again using the button, the dialog becomes undraggable.

Comment: actually I haven't changed my code. It's the same as it was. The JavaScript code is called by an onclick event of a html button.